# Switch buttons on only the left-handed mouse (input devices)

Tags: debian, gnome, devices, wayland, peripherals

I've got two Logitech M650 Mice hooked to by Debian 12 Gnome 44 Machine. One is a "Left-Handed" mouse. I would like to swap the buttons on just the left mouse so that I can use my index finger as primary click. The right mouse should remain the same.

When I `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` here are the results:

```
I: Bus=0005 Vendor=046d Product=b02a Version=0013
N: Name="Logitech Signature M650 L Mouse"
P: Phys=4c:1d:96:47:de:e2
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B02A.0022/input/input46
U: Uniq=d5:55:b1:dd:b7:7f
H: Handlers=mouse3 event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0005 Vendor=046d Product=b02a Version=0013
N: Name="Logitech Signature M650 L Left-Handed Mouse"
P: Phys=4c:1d:96:47:de:e2
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B02A.0023/input/input47
U: Uniq=de:9d:c9:d8:74:fc
H: Handlers=mouse4 event16 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10
```

Can some one point me in the right direction. Thanks!